# NodeJS and angular 2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I want to create app with nodeJS and angular2 as client side framework. I have created node project and in public folder create whole angular project with angular-cli. I have routes in nodeJS

```
// api routes
app.get('/api/getSomeData', function(req, res){
    res.json({'data': 'Dummy Data'});
});

// Redirect all other routes to angular index file
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/src/index.html');
});
```

I cant serve angulars index.html page. I dont know if i must build angular and how to do build.

Comment: Where are JS files? Are you also redirecting them to `index.html`?

Comment: All angular files are in public folder of nodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it. After ng build command in angular root folder ( node/public ) and next line of code in nodes main file ( my is server.js ) all is good and angular is loaded as is should.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/dist'));
```

and node route

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/dist/index.html');
});
```

Comment: remove `app.get` as AngularJS is already served from static folder.